# A lot of time spend in pass object in js

Tags: javascript

I write function like

```
function isSupport(Element)
{
    //do something
}
```

The Element is an Object named "Element".And "Element" have some subclasses like "Instance" , "symbol" and so on.When I pass a subclass of "Element" to this function.I find it will cost me 0.002s - 0.003s to jump to the function;Is it commonly in javascript to pass an Object?I doubt that i has copy an "Element".

What's the reason on earth?

Thanks!

I use following code to show time passed:

```
function getTimePass()
{
    var date1 = new Date();
    var time1 = date1.getTime() - time ;
    fl.trace("time passed" +time1/1000+"s");
}
```

The fl.trace() is debug output method.
I measure the time:

```
getTimePass();
isSupport(Elmement);
getTimePass();
```

Also in isSupport();

```
function isSupport(Element)
{
    getTimePass();
    //to do
    getTimePass();
}
```

1st call of getTimepass() and 2nd call of it have 0.003s interval generally.

Comment: how did you measure the time to see your function be called after 0.002s~0.003s? can you make sure the element object is ready prior to call your function?

Comment: Element object is inner object of other program.It always ready to call my funciton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Precise time intervals in JS

Be aware that `Date` objects aren't very precise.

If you want presision, you should use the [Performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) API ([`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29)):

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

## Function calls are expensive

See slides 10-19 of http://www.slideshare.net/madrobby/extreme-javascript-performance

## Pass an object to a function

Yes, in JavaScript it's common to pass an object to a function.

And no, your object isn't copied. In fact, in JavaScript, objects aren't stored directly in variables: variables only contain a reference to the object. Then, when you pass an object to a function, you only pass the reference.

Comment: Thank you very much!I think the time is spent by function call :-)